# Why cannot login in to the server via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, login

The network connection is OK as I can ping that server. However, I cannot SSH to it by any user. The output as follows,

```
Auth User/Pass with PS...fail...Please reconnect!.
Connection to xxx closed.
```

There is no problem of my password. Is it due to any high load average or error configuration?

And this is the verbose output after input my password,

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US
Auth User/Pass with PS...fail...Please reconnect!.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to xxx closed.
Transferred: sent 1640, received 1256 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7131.6, received 5461.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: At minimum paste the output of 'ssh -v user@host' ?

Comment: The verbose output after input password, "debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US
Auth User/Pass with PS...fail...Please reconnect!.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to o closed.
Transferred: sent 1640, received 1256 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7131.6, received 5461.8
debug1: Exit status 0"

Comment: Can you ensure that no other machine on your network has the same ip?

Answer (score 1):

Start with some basics.

- Does the server have the SSH service running?
- Is the appropriate port open on the server?
- Will the server accept an SSH connection form the client's address?
- Are you trying to access it on the correct port?

Answer (score 0):

If you ssh from the server to 127.0.0.1 do you get the same error? I had a problem with ssh that turned out to be a corrupt auth key.

Also what version of Linux are you using? Note, root cannot login via ssh by default in some distro's

You can run top to see if you have a run away process. Unless your server is really extraordinarily busy I would think ssh would still work.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the error "*Auth User/Pass with PS...fail...Please reconnect!*", turns out I was trying to connect to the IPMI address rather than the host itself.

Hope that helps!